# How to use javascript variables to set image source and image title?

Tags: javascript, variables, src

all. I have the following JavaScript variable `strVar`. I want to use variables to set the `src` attribute and the image title.

```
 var strVar="";
    strVar += "<img src=\"http:\/\/somesite.com\/3\/ok\/images\/123456.png\"\/><b>mango<\/b><br><span class=\"centerKeyContainer\">";
```

I want to use variables like this:

```
var strVar="";
strVar += "<img src=\""+imageSource+""\/><b>"+imageTitle+<\/b><br><span class=\"centerKeyContainer\">";
```

But the above keeps giving me a syntax error! Could anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Second slash is wrongly escaped
2. Missing quote after `imageTitle`
3. Don't need to escape slash before closing `/b`

   ```
   strVar += "<img src=\""+imageSource+"\"/><b>"+imageTitle+"</b><br><span class=\"centerKeyContainer\">";
   ```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Missing escape character for the double quote after imageSource.  Missing a double quote after imageTitle.

```
strVar += "<img src=\""+imageSource+"\"\/><b>"+imageTitle+"<\/b><br><span class=\"centerKeyContainer\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var strVar="";
strVar += "<img src=\""+imageSource+""\/><b>"+imageTitle+<\/b><br><span class=\"centerKeyContainer\">";
```

Here the quotes after the "imageSource" variable name are not escaped correctly. The second quote should be escapes as below and the code should look like this

```
strVar += "<img src=\""+imageSource+"\"/><b>"+imageTitle+"</b><br><span class=\"centerKeyContainer\">";
```